# parsing string or json in bash (shell)

Tags: python, json, bash, shell

please help me.

I have the string (json request) :

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":[{"hostid":"10158"}],"id":1}
```

i try to parsing it with command :

```
reference_id2=`echo "$reference_id" | python -c 'import json, sys; print json.load(sys.stdin)["result"]'`
```

and still have `[{u'hostid': u'10158'}]`

How i can get only 10158 (like in example)

THanks.

P.S. this is doesn't work too :

```
reference_id2=`echo "$reference_id" | python -c 'import json, sys; print json.load(sys.stdin)["result"]["hostid"]'`
```

Comment: `result` is a list. You need to index into it before you can get `hostid` out. (The error for that second example should have tipped you off about that.) Try `...["result"][0]["hostid"]'`

Answer (score 2):

In your sample `result` is an array. To get `hostid` you need to specify item index:

```
json.load(sys.stdin)["result"][0]["hostid"]
```

So your code shoud be like:

```
reference_id2=`echo "$reference_id" | python -c 'import json, sys; print json.load(sys.stdin)["result"][0]["hostid"]'`
```

Answer (score 2):

Give `jq` a try. It's the easiest way to parse JSON in the shell.

```
$ jq -r '.result[0].hostid' <<< "$json"
10158
```